# Jquery click event for object with class containing a word

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use this:

```
$("[class*=welcome]").click( function(){  e.t.c........
```

the selector is not working? I was expecting this to trigger when any object has the word welcome in it.

thank you.

Comment: "in it" - What is "it"? The `class` attribute text, or the text contents of the element?

Answer (score 4):

```
<div class="welcome_something"></div>
```

will work with

```
$("[class*='welcome']")
```

and

```
<div class="something">You are welcome</div>
```

will work with

```
$("div:contains('welcome')")
```

Comment: Unless there's a space in the value, you don't need the `'`.

Comment: @JaredFarrish - You're right, you don't have to use the extra set of quotes, but I always do, and so do the examples in the jQuery doc's, so I think it's good practice to do so, and then you won't forget them when you need them

Comment: That's understandable, but I felt it necessary not to construe that one change as the difference-maker here.

Comment: And you are correct, the quotes have no effect on this particular example, I just added them since I always tend to write it that way myself.